# Why can't I `source` ssh-agent and ssh-add with in bash script?

Tags: bash, ssh, ssh-agent

When I tried `git push`, I get the following error.

```
ERROR: Repository not found.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I know that I should specify my own key here, so I type the following in bash window, and it works fine.

```
ssh-agent bash
ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa_lrz
git push
```

However, I'd like make things easy, so I have a set_env.sh like this

```
ssh-agent bash
ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa_lrz
```

And I type in my bash window like this

```
. set_env.sh
git push
```

However, I get the `ERROR: Repository not found.` error again, but why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because when you run :

```
. set_env.sh
```

You will be inside the bash session setup by `ssh-agent bash` where `ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa_lrz` has not run yet.

What you need is putting in set_env.sh

```
eval "$(/usr/bin/ssh-agent)"
ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa_lrz
```